# Gatilho (Trigger) no phpmyadmin está copiando multiplicando registros

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Sou iniciante e tenho pouca experiência com MySQL, mas tenho estudado e praticado e as coisas estão caminhando bem, e estou precisando da ajuda de vocês porque estou preso numa situação que não consigo achar solução, e tenho vasculhado bastante. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, um CRUD um pouco mais sofisticado, onde importo uma tabela do excel em csv para uma tabela no Mysql (tabela 1:`adup_c_alunos`). Esta etapa está ok. Depois, preciso copiar alguns campos dessa tabela com seus referidos dados (rows) para uma outra (tabela 2:`audp_lig_alunoturma`). Pensei em fazer isso á medida que os dados vão chegando à primeira tabela. Então optei por usar a função de "Gatilhos", do phpmyadmin, que é como eu sei fazer até o momento, como segue a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está sendo feito uma cópia entre as tabelas, mas da seguinte maneira, pelo que entendi:

1. Um primeiro registro (row) é copiado da tabela 1 para a tabela 2:
2. Na sequência, um segundo registro é copiado, mais o primeiro que já tinha sido copiado;
3. A seguir, é copiado o terceiro, mais o segundo, mais o primeiro novamente, e assim por diante.

Desta forma, até esse momento no exemplo, no terceiro passo já teríamos na tabela 2 "6" registros: 1 do passo 1, 2 do passo 2 e 3 do passo 3.
O que eu preciso é que copie apenas um de cada. Já usei DISTINCT e UNIQUE e não consegui achar uma maneira de resolver isso.

Essa é a minha dúvida que peço a quem puder me orientar. Antecipadamente já agradeço.

** UPDATE **

Tentei executando o código abaixo no SQL do phpmyadmin, mas recebi mensagem de "erro de sintaxe no SQL próximo a '' na linha 7"

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS transfer;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER transfer AFTER INSERT ON audp_c_alunos
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO audp_lig_alunoturma (id_aluno, id_turma,nomealuno, turma)
    SELECT id_alunos, id_turma, nomealuno, turma
    FROM audp_c_alunos
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Repare que não está a aplicar filtros na pesquisa. Dessa forma está sempre a seleccionar toda a tabela. Tem de filtrar o select  (do insert select) pela linha que foi inserida.

Tente colocar o filtro referindo a chave primária (ou chave única) da linha inserida como (assumindo que o campo `id_alunos` é uma chave única):

```
 (...)
 FROM audp_c_alunos
 WHERE id_alunos = NEW.id_alunos
 (...)
```